# ArcGIS Script Tool RuntimeError: cannot open 'GPL0'

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-script-tool

I Cannot find what this error means or what could be causing it? Script worked until I added the lines under "Set map label to containing quad name". My environment is ArcGIS 10.1 SP1, Windows 7. Here is my code:

```py
import arcpy

#Define I/O and workspaces
arcpy.env.workspace = "FolderPath"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("MXDPath.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
outpath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

def getAuthCode(lon):
    if lon >= -126.0 and lon < -120.0:
        authCode = 26910 #UTM Zone 10N
    elif lon >= -120.0 and lon < -114.0:
        authCode = 26911 #UTM Zone 11N
    elif lon >= -114.0 and lon < -108.0:
        authCode = 26912 #UTM Zone 12N
    elif lon >= -108.0 and lon < -102.0:
        authCode = 26913 #UTM Zone 13N
    elif lon >= -102.0 and lon < -96.0:
        authCode = 26914 #UTM Zone 14N
    elif lon >= -96.0 and lon < -90.0:
        authCode = 26915 #UTM Zone 15N
    elif lon >= -90.0 and lon < -84.0:
        authCode = 26916 #UTM Zone 16N
    elif lon >= -84.0 and lon < -78.0:
        authCode = 26917 #UTM Zone 17N
    elif lon >= -78.0 and lon < -72.0:
        authCode = 26918 #UTM Zone 18N
    elif lon >= -72.0 and lon < -66.0:
        authCode = 26919 #UTM Zone 19N
    else:
        authCode = 4326 # WGS84
    return authCode

#Create extent/spatial referenece objects
lat = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
lon = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
WGS84 = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326) #Creates spatial reference variable to switch back to later
UTM = arcpy.SpatialReference(getAuthCode(lon))
df.spatialReference = WGS84 #Set spatial reference to WGS84
resetPT = arcpy.Extent(-97.747957, 30.280553, -97.747957, 30.280553)

#Set map label to containing quad name
point = arcpy.Point(lon, lat)
ptGeo = arcpy.PointGeometry(point, WGS84)
quadPath = "LayerPath.lyr"
quadLyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(quadPath) #arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
selectedLyr = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(quadLyr, "INTERSECT", ptGeo)
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(selectedLyr, "QUAD_NAME")
quadName = ""
for row in cursor:
    quadName = str(row)
label = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "Label")[0]
label.text = "NWI Map" + "\n" + "Quad: " + quadName[3:-3] + ", TX"
label.elementPositionX = 0.3
label.elementPositionY = 0.3

#Pans to centerpoint and sets scale to 1:12000
extent = arcpy.Extent(lon, lat, lon, lat)
df.panToExtent(extent)
df.spatialReference = UTM #Temporarily set spatial reference to correct UTM zone
df.scale = 12000
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

#Export map to ES# folder
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, outpath, resolution=300) #exportToPDF

#Reset extent/spatial reference
df.spatialReference = WGS84 
df.panToExtent(resetPT)
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

mxd.save()
```

Comment: Are you running this in the Python Window inside ArcMap or as a Script tool?

Comment: I'm running it as a script tool

Comment: Is there an error message? That would help a lot. Is FolderPath a substitue for a real path that has been changed to protect your anonymity? Is your layer file "LayerPath.lyr" a full path? if not does it exist in your workspace?

Comment: It's in the title "Runtime error: cannot open 'GPL0'". Yes, I took out the full paths

Comment: Normally there's a bit more info in the error message, the traceback can be vital to locating the root cause of a problem. Is the feature class referenced by the layer called GPL0 by any chance?

Comment: If the answer provided by @MrBubbles does not resolve this for you, and in future questions, I think you should try to cut your code down to a code snippet that shows the same error before presenting it. That way where to look for the issue becomes more obvious to you and us.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson you were correct, there was more to the error I just didn't scroll up. It references the line in which I assign the cursor, the GPL0 doesn't exist or is not supported for the selectedLyr variable. When I was testing in the Python window I used the quad layer in the TOC (with "" marks) and everything worked. Now that I'm using file paths for the quadLyr (also tried the ListLayers line which is commented out) I can't create a cursor or use MakeFeatureLayer either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The SelectLayerByLocation method changes the state of the quadLyr object, so instead of assigning the method to selectedLyr I ran the method and then used quadLyr as input for the cursor.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is essentially saying that it can't open the layer file due to the manner in which you provided it. Esri loves cryptic errors like that.

If you're running this as a Script Tool, I suspect the issue is with the manner in which you reference the quadPath variable. That's not a normal way to reference a layer file saved on disk. The way you're doing it is what I typically see when people are working with the Python Window, because the Python Window has a built-in list of all the items in the Table of Contents and there it references items in that built-in list according to their namespace.

Try referencing that Layer file using its absolute path instead.